# Something wrong at $\int \frac{x^2}{x^2+2x+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have to calculate $$\int \frac{x^2}{x^2+2x+1}dx$$ and I obtain: $$\int \frac{x^2}{x^2+2x+1}dx=\frac{-x^2}{x+1}+2\left(x-\log\left(x+1\right)\right)$$
but I verify on wolfram and this is equal with:  $$x-\frac{1}{x+1}-2\log\left(x+1\right)$$ where did I go wrong?

---

**P.S:** Here is all steps: $$\int \:\frac{x^2}{x^2+2x+1}dx=-\frac{x^2}{x+1}+\int \:\frac{2x}{x+1}dx=-\frac{x^2}{x+1}+2\left(x-\log\left(x+1\right)\right)$$ I am sure that is not wrong, but the form on wolfram seems easily then it.

Comment: Can you show some of your intermediate steps, please?

Comment: Surely, look: $\int \:\frac{x^2}{x^2+2x+1}dx=-\frac{x^2}{x+1}+\int \:\frac{2x}{x+1}dx=-\frac{x^2}{x+1}+2\left(x-log\left(x+1\right)\right)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is equivalent, since

$$\frac{-x^2}{x+1} + 2x  = \frac{2x^2 + 2x-x^2}{x+1} = \frac{x^2 + 2x + 1 - 1}{x+1} = x - \frac{1}{x+1} +1$$

and it differs by a constant $1$.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is what I want to see, not another methods, good job !

Comment: You good job!!!

Answer (score 3):

$$\int \frac{x^2}{x^2+2x+1}=\int\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^2+2x+1}+\int \frac{-2x-2}{x^2+2x+1}+\int \frac{1}{x^2+2x+1} $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I do, but isn't what I ask... I don't need other methods, I asked just what is wrong with my method...

Answer (score 3):

setting $$x+1=t$$ then we get the integral $$\int \frac{(t-1)^2}{t^2}dt=\int\left(1-\frac{2}{t}+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)dt$$

Comment: I (not OP) tried this too and I got $t-2ln(t)-\frac1t$, which is resubstituted $x+1-\frac{1}{x+1}-2ln(x+1)$ , which is not equal to what WolframAlpha says. Where's the mistake?

Comment: Hey Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, your method is intresting, but I want to know in my method what I wrong, because I think all my steps is correct!

Comment: @Christian 1 is a constant and is abosrbed by C, where C is set of all constants, because we have indefinite integral !

Comment: $x+1-\frac{1}{x+1}-2\ln(x+1)$ is right you can test this by differentiating this with respect to $x$

Answer (score 2):

You are not wrong: your answer and the Wolfram answer differ by a constant. Both answers have a term of $-2\log(x+1)$. As for the rest:
$$
\text{(Yours) - (Wolfram)} = \left(2x - {x^2\over x+1}\right)
-
\left(x - {1\over x+1}\right)
=
x - {x^2-1\over x+1} = x - (x-1) = 1
$$

Comment: Yes, now I realize it... in the future I'll try to be more careful !

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write $$\frac{x^{2}}{\left(x+1\right)^{2}}=1+\frac{1}{\left(x+1\right)^{2}}-\frac{2}{x+1}.
 $$